# C# error CS1519

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this:

> error CS1519 Unexpected symbol '{' in class, struct, or interface
>   member declaration

regarding this:

```
void LineRendererUpdate (); {
    Vector2 catapultToProjectile = transform.position - catapultLineFront.transform.position;
    leftCatapultToProjectile.direction = catapultToProjectile;
    Vector3 holdPoint = leftCatapultToProjectile.GetPoint(catapultToProjectile.magnitude + circleRadius);
    catapultLineFront.SetPosition(1, holdPoint);
    catapultLineBack.SetPosition(1, holdPoint);
}
```

And I do not know why. I am very new to coding in general but even more so to c#.

Comment: try to follow what the error complier gave you to start with, it showing that there is an unexpected symbol  `{` so points out that you are having `;` after  `LineRendererUpdate ()`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon (;) in the first line. Only when calling a method do you want a semi colon after the method.

The fixed code should look as follows:

```
 void LineRendererUpdate () 
 {
    Vector2 catapultToProjectile = transform.position - catapultLineFront.transform.position;
    leftCatapultToProjectile.direction = catapultToProjectile;
    Vector3 holdPoint = leftCatapultToProjectile.GetPoint(catapultToProjectile.magnitude + circleRadius);
    catapultLineFront.SetPosition(1, holdPoint);
    catapultLineBack.SetPosition(1, holdPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon in this line

```
void LineRendererUpdate (); {
```

so the compiler can understand that is a method what you have there

Comment: thanks. Because I cannot ask another question so soon, I will ask it here.

Comment: I am getting this: